# Matlab -> Python, how do I convert binary file to 1d float array? Works fine in Matlab but unable to reproduce in Python

Tags: python, matlab

In Matlab, binary file section 'block' is 2048 bytes and is read as follows:

```
fseek(fileID, 2024, 'bof');
data = fread(fileID, block, '*float');
```

Output of data is a 2048x1 single precision array, example below...

```
15.5567
-1.9876
0.0529
25.97620
```

In Python, I make sure to seek to same section of the file and use 2048 bytes 'block' to read the binary section. I then tried to use struct unpack function to convert the binary to the single precision floating numbers.

```
fileID.seek(2024,0)
data = unpack('2048f',block)
```

First, I get errors for bytes object of length. So I change size to see if atleast the output will give me something similar.

```
data = unpack('512f',block)
print(data)
```

Output gives very small and larger numbers

```
-14.858826637268066
5.938749347655264e-36
1.767982006072998
-24509016064.0
```

Any help is appreciated. I also tried to use

```
data = numpy.frombuffer(block, dtype=numpy.float32)
```

with basically same results.

Comment: It seems the numbers are encoded differently. what you can do is to read it in Matlab, output it in some generic format (e.g. text file with each line representing a number) and read it in python

Comment: I solved it! Sometimes just takes asking the question. I used the following:      
                  for i in range(0, 2048):
                          data.append(unpack('>f', fileID.read(4))[0]

Comment: I don't think I was "reading" the file in python before trying to unpack it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I found. Works perfectly.

```
 data = []

 for i in range(0, 2048): 
    data.append(unpack('>f', fileID.read(4))[0]
```

The output of data is exactly the same as Matlab.